# Add macro code to a worksheet through a module

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I currently have a macro created which takes a large amount of data (pulled from a database weekly) and displays it in multiple different pivot tables. I also have a summary page at the start of the workbook listing different customer and machine names. Currently I have a macro written so that I can click on one of the customer names and it opens the sheet corosponding to that customer via a Worksheet_SelectionChange event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If SheetExists(Right(Replace(Replace(ActiveCell.Value, "/", "-"), "'", ""), 31)) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Right(Replace(Replace(ActiveCell.Value, "/", "-"), "'", ""), 31)).Activate
    End If
End Sub

Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional wb As Excel.Workbook)
   Dim s As Excel.Worksheet
   If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   On Error Resume Next
   Set s = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
   On Error GoTo 0
   SheetExists = Not s Is Nothing
End Function
```

Unfortunatly due to the nature of the job, I can't share too much of the code itself.

My problem lies when the report is re generated next week: is it possible to have the macro which generates the detailed sheets and the summery add the SelectionChange code to the new summary? Thanks!

Comment: Use an addin to do this, or a template

Comment: What does your data look like? Can you show the code of your macro?

Comment: Updated with the event code, unfortunatly I can't show very much of the generating macro

Comment: And I always thought that the data is confidential and not the VBA code you are writing. Anyway, the essential problem is that you are looking for VBA code to change VBA code. While this is possible, I am only aware of VBA code to change VBA code residing in modules. Yet, you want to change the code on a sheet. To my knowledge this is not possible. Hence, the best advise is still what @Nathan_Sav suggested: template or addin. I normally go with templates (empty) on a SharePoint site (with access tracking, versioning, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

A template seemed to be the best option for this

Thanks!